# Jersey + Embedded Tomcat Minimal Maven Configuration

Tags: maven, tomcat, jersey, jersey-client

Could anyone provide simple configuration of Jersey and Embedded Tomcat in:
1) pom.xml
2) main method

I was trying to find it in google search, but they propose to use grizzly, glassfish and etc.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [webapp-runner](https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner) to run the web app.  It deploys the maven generated war from /target into a built in tomcat container.  This is how java applications gets deployed on Heroku. 
pom plugin configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0.34.1</version>
                                <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
        <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.34.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

to run the application after `mvn clean package`

```
java -jar target\dependency\webapp-runner.jar target\myapp.war
```